# Error ao fazer contador via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, count

Estou tentando fazendo um contador de pendencias ao meu sistema, só que está dando erro, na hora de fazer o calculo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Está dando error no .Count como podem ver na foto abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            if (!Cookies.Exists("hid"))
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new { area = "Entrar" });

            var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));
            var listaDia1 = await Dia1Service.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaDia2 = await Dia2Service.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaDia3 = await Dia3Service.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaDia7 = await Dia7Service.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var lista90Dias = await Dados90DiasService.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaAlta = await AltaUTIService.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaDemografia = await DemografiaContatosService.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            var listaDadosBasais = await DadosBasaisService.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);

            ViewBag.listaD1 = listaDia1;
            ViewBag.listaD2 = listaDia2;
            ViewBag.listaD3 = listaDia3;
            ViewBag.listaD7 = listaDia7;
            ViewBag.lista90d = lista90Dias;
            ViewBag.listaAlta = listaAlta;
            ViewBag.listaDeC = listaDemografia;
            ViewBag.listaDb = listaDadosBasais;
            return View();
        }
```

**Meu Contator em PendenciaFilter.cs**

```
void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            AtualizarNotificacoes(filterContext);
        }

        private void AtualizarNotificacoes(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookies.GetCookie("uid"))) return;

            var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));

            // Pegar todas as notificações deste usuario
            var altaUtiPendencias = new AltaUtiService().GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId).Count();
            var dia1Pendencias = new Dia1Service().GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId).ToString();
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.QtdPendencias = altaUtiPendencias + dia1Pendencias;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

O seu repositório retorna um `async Task<IEnumerable<object>>`, então você precisa de um `await` para acessar a coleção (que possui o método `Count`)

```
`(await new AltaUtiService().GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId)).Count()`
```

Eu realmente espero que este seu `AltaUtiService.GetPendenciasByUser` não esteja chamando um `ToListAsync` antes de devolver a coleção.

### `Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?`

**EDIT**

você deve modificar o seu filtro para que ele executar o `AtualizarNotificacoes` de forma síncrona.:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted (ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    AtualizarNotificacoes(filterContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task AtualizarNotificacoes(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookies.GetCookie("uid"))) return;

    var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));

    // Pegar todas as notificações deste usuario
    var altaUtiPendencias = (await new AltaUtiService().GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId)).Count();
    var dia1Pendencias = (await new Dia1Service().GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId)).ToString();
    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.QtdPendencias = altaUtiPendencias + dia1Pendencias;
}
```

Comment: E no metodo  void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            AtualizarNotificacoes(filterContext);
        } 

eu preciso mexer alguma coisa?

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo pronto

Comment: Tobias você pode dar uma olhada nesta imagem?
http://prntscr.com/ix2hgk
Eu realmente estou com muitas duvidas em relação a isto não estou conseguindo entender

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo foi um erro meu, Action Filters assíncronos estão presentes apenas no Core. Então terá de fazer uma chamada síncrona ao método assíncrono.

Comment: No lugar do (ActionExecutedContext contex) seria (ActionExecutedContext filterContext) correto?

Comment: Fiz a correção em meu codigo, aparentemente funcinou, só que na hora que eu executo meu sistema. ele fica Carregando... e não abre o sistema, porem não da nenhum erro.

Eu tenho em meu sistema um FilterConfig.cs será que eu teria que mexer nele também em relação a isto?

public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new PendenciaFilter());
        }

Comment: Pode ser um deadlock na chamada assincronia, o ideal mesmo seria chamar uma versão síncrona da consulta. Sem falar que estes seus serviços estão me cheirando a problema.

Comment: você tem algum exemplo de como eu realizar está modificação?